# FactoryGirl - Factory not registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

In my Rails project, I have added factory_girl_rails gem and I am getting an error when I run Rspec to test my factory:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/khack/blister/spec/factories/user.rb:1: 
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,    expecting keyword_end
 passw...ester@example.com"
...                               ^
/Users/khack/blister/test/spec/factories/user.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected 
tIDENTIFIER,     expecting keyword_end
 endassword "password"m"
 ...                               ^
```

The user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Aaron Sumner"
    email "tester@example.com"
    password "password"
  end
end
```

I am missing something but I can't find it. Any guesses?

Comment: Missing `do` on `FactoryGirl.define do`

Comment: Whoops. sorry I missed that here. It turns out that it is FactoryGirl.define do in the code. Thanks for pointing that out to me

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was non-breaking space that my code editor was adding. I did another factory in a different editor and it registered successfully.